# match doesnt work after adding delimiters

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using a simple regex to test a string, it works just fine until I add delimiters to it. Can someone please explain why is this happening, do I have to add the delimiters in every regex?

```
var Cont = $("#input").val(),
    cCheck = "^[0-9a-zA-Z\-\u0590-\u05FF !?.,]+$", //this one works
    cCheckB = "/^[0-9a-zA-Z\-\u0590-\u05FF !?.,]+$/"; //this one doesnt


if(!Cont.match(cCheck)){
    alert("bad"); return false;
}
else{
    alert("good"); return false;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do **not** quote a [regexp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) in JavaScript when using delimiters.

```
var cCheckB = /^[0-9a-zA-Z\-\u0590-\u05FF !?.,]+$/;
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are trying to use a regular expression literal, which in javascript is delimited with '/'. However, if you use that you don't want the quotes around it.

```
cCheck = /^[0-9a-zA-Z\-\u0590-\u05FF !?.,]+$/
```